# Why does plt.quiver flattens the vectors when I give angles?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, visualization

So i tried to use plt.quiver, but i couldn't align the vectors to the grids. When I try to use angles = "xy" it flattens the vectors. When i use angles = "uv" its not aligned.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

v1 = np.array([[2],[2]])
V = 0
U = 0

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,10))
ax1 = plt.subplot(2,1,1)

ax1.quiver(V, U, v1[0], v1[1], scale = 1, units= "xy",angles = "uv")
ax1.set_ylim(-3,3)
ax1.set_xlim(-3,3)
ax1.grid()

ax2 = plt.subplot(2,1,2)

ax2.quiver(V, U, v1[0], v1[1], scale = 1, units= "xy",angles = "uv")
ax2.set_ylim(-3,3)
ax2.set_xlim(-3,3)
ax2.grid()

plt.show()
```

Error code when using angles ="xy":

The error code : ...\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\quiver.py:609:
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
lengths = np.hypot(*dxy.T) / eps

The plot:

When angles = "xy": https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DFd9.png

When angles = "uv": https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB5dv.png

I'm a little bit new to the quiver function and I'm not sure how could i solve this.

Comment: too much code, please reduce to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i was able to run all the code here:   https://pythonforundergradengineers.com/quiver-plot-with-matplotlib-and-jupyter-notebooks.html  i suggest that you read the docs and follow with a basic example leading from this.

Comment: Thank you @D.L , I've changed the code, to a shorter one and I've read the page that you linked, but I'm still not sure about the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an artifact (bug?) of how matplotlib is trying to scale the arrows.

In the source of `Quiver`, [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/c23ccdde6f0f8c071b09a88770e24452f2859e99/lib/matplotlib/quiver.py#L631) there is the following lines:

```
if str_angles == 'xy' and self.scale_units == 'xy':
    # Here eps is 1 so that if we get U, V by diffing
    # the X, Y arrays, the vectors will connect the
    # points, regardless of the axis scaling (including log).
    angles, lengths = self._angles_lengths(U, V, eps=1)
elif str_angles == 'xy' or self.scale_units == 'xy':
    # Calculate eps based on the extents of the plot
    # so that we don't end up with roundoff error from
    # adding a small number to a large.
    eps = np.abs(self.axes.dataLim.extents).max() * 0.001
    angles, lengths = self._angles_lengths(U, V, eps=eps)
```

The key line being `eps = np.abs(self.axes.dataLim.extents).max() * 0.001` inside the second if block, which is what applies to your call to `quiver(...)`.

All of your data is located at (0,0), which means `self.axes.dataLim.extents` are zero, and so `eps` is in turn zero.

The error:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide lengths = np.hypot(*dxy.T) / eps
```

you see is because of a division by zero [later on](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/c23ccdde6f0f8c071b09a88770e24452f2859e99/lib/matplotlib/quiver.py#L616), which tries to use that `eps` value as a denominator.

You can work-around this either by passing `scale_units="xy"` to the `quiver(...)` call, or by calling [update_datalim](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.update_datalim.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.update_datalim) on your axes. E.g.

```
ax1.update_datalim([(-3, -3), (3, 3)])  # Force axis datalimits to include area we want to view.
```

or

```
ax1.quiver(V, U, v1[0], v1[1], scale=1, units="xy", angles="uv", scale_units="xy")
```

Comment: I've tried to use the scale_units="xy" and it worked for me! Thank you very much for your help and explanation!